# Want the Windows 10 start menu to show the expanded start menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, desktop

I am customizing the Windows 10 desktop, and am wondering if it is possible to make the start menu show the menu that one sees when they click the expand button, by default. Here's what I mean:

Normal:

[image: Normally]

After Expanding:

[image: After Expand]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's the small icons option.

1. Right Click the taskbar.
2. Choose 'settings'.
3. Turn 'Off' Use small Icons option.

This will show the expanded start menu

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me. The only thing that settings changes is smaller icons in the taskbar or regular sized icons in the taskbar.

Comment: @Stese - That is for taskbar icons not the start menu. Could you share screenshots if it worked for you?